# How to align a Wordpress navigation bar to the right of a logo?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to get my navigation bar to the right of the logo in my Wordpress theme. It's being built with Underscores. I've managed to line up the primary navigation and the logo the way I want it, basically, with this CSS:

```
.main-navigation {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: -4em;
    width: 55%;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    float: right;
}
```

and here's a picture of how I want it to look:[image: website logo with navigation to the right]

I understand that negative margins (assuming `top: -4em;` is considered with negative margins) aren't elegant or the best way to handle these sorts of things. Plus, I generally find these kinds of workarounds usually come back to bite me later on.

I'm new to playing around with JSFiddle, so I hope I've done this correctly! Here's my code, now condensed!: http://jsfiddle.net/DMDesigns/d39ej96r/11/

What's the best way to make this happen? I've been searching, seen a lot of people ask this question, but many of the answers have been too specific to their website to help me.

Comment: It would be easier to look at if you created a fiddle that only contained relevant html and css for the menu.

Comment: Thanks! I updated it. http://jsfiddle.net/DMDesigns/d39ej96r/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me the better part of the day to figure out, yesterday, but disappointed with the lack of responses, here's what I figured out. I'm posting it here for anyone else having a similar problem.

First, I took the logo (named .header-image) and added:

```
float: left;
position: relative;
```

Then I took the navigation I wanted to the left of (named .main-navigation) and removed my workaround, which was

```
float: right; 
top: -4em; 
width: 55%;
```

and changed clear:both; to clear:none;

I added a little personal CSS to my .main-navigation to make it match the logo which was

```
 height: 112px;
 background: #69d7f9;
 z-index: -1;
 padding: 28px 0;
```

and I removed any floats from .main navigation ul.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a main div and insert both logo and navigation section in the same div with float:left; for both of them. Let me know if you get this or I'll let you know by an example.

Comment: They're both wrapped in <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner"> and I tried to use .site-header to add a float: left with no luck. Is that what you mean or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: If you can send me the code for both HTML & CSS, may be I can help you.

Comment: The useful code is at the link I posted:  jsfiddle.net/DMDesigns/d39ej96r/11

Comment: You have unnecessarily used </ul></li> somewhere in between even when they are not initiated somewhere. Can you please let me know how you want your menu to be? Because the way you have coded HTML file is causing links to distribute unevenly. Let me know soon.

Comment: The picture in the question is how I want the navigation to look. If you're taking about the HTML with the navigation, that is not done by me. This is a wordpress page so the actual code looks like this: <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
   <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'margins' ); ?></button>
   <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Using the Underscores starter theme for WordPress, the navigation bar can be floated to the right of the logo (or site title) using the following method:

Add the following CSS to your style-sheet:

```
.site-branding{
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.site-description{
    display: none;     
}
#site-navigation{
    float: right;
    clear: none;
    width: auto;
}
```

These instructions are based on the Underscores theme as is before customisation.